# How to make localStorage persist even after reloading of the browser?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, local-storage

I have made a react app with mongodb and express with a simple authentication system. After signup, the User model with my credentials gets saved to the localStorage like this:

```
{
    bio: ""
    email: "myemail@gmail.com"
    name: "myName"
    role: "user"
    _id: "5e9b42d31040cb0fc54c6936"
}
```

After login I want to update the bio property, or to add some since is empty initialy, so in order to do that I have made a axios call like this:

```
async function updateBiography (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        try {
            const res = await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/biography/${id}`, { bioVal });

            setBioVal(res.bio);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

So this thing is returning the updated value of bio, saving it to the database, no problem here. But I want to update the value of bio in the browser as well, and I want that to happen instantly as I submit. In order to achieve that I have done this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    currentUser['bio'] = bioCurrentValue;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
}, [reload]);
```

After this the item in localStorage is like this:

```
{
    bio: "the new value",
    ...
}
```

Awesome. The problem I have is that after reloading the browser the localStorage does not keep the update.
After reloading the item in the localStorage it becomes as before:

```
{
    bio: "",
    ...
}
```

How can I make the updates persist in the localStorage?

Answer (score 3):

Local storage is normally persistent, but you're subject to the browser settings of the user.

If in some private browsing mode, or with some other privacy extensions, it's common for the storage to be wiped out.  Nothing you can do about this if this is what the user wants.